# Is it possible to get the API response from Antd's upload action after the upload is done?

Tags: reactjs, upload, next.js, antd

I'm using Antd's Upload component to handle my image uploads to Cloudinary. When the file is uploaded it returns details about the file, which includes the file URL on the server. I need to get that file URL from the response after Antd's Upload component finishes the upload, any idea how I can do that?

Or do I need to just handle that on my own by writing my own custom request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onChange function exposed by Ant Design's upload component includes a some data about the upload in it's prop.

You could use the `file.response` property to retrieve the response returned from your upload service.

See below from [Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/upload/#onChange):

```
{
  file: {
     uid: 'uid',      // unique identifier, negative is recommend, to prevent interference with internal generated id
     name: 'xx.png',   // file name
     status: 'done', // options：uploading, done, error, removed. Intercepted file by beforeUpload don't have status field.
     response: '{"status": "success"}', // response from server
     linkProps: '{"download": "image"}', // additional html props of file link
     xhr: 'XMLHttpRequest{ ... }', // XMLHttpRequest Header
  },
  fileList: [ /* ... */ ],
  event: { /* ... */ },
}
```

An example of how to implement the onChange function is available in the first example on the [Upload Component documentation](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-basic).

```
const props = {
  name: 'file',
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'authorization-text',
  },
  onChange(info) {
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        // Handle response from API
        console.log(info.file.response);
    }
  },
};

return (
    <Upload {...props}>
        <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
)
```